# Junior Dev (Starting Out) Guidance : DTO and creating the object

Tags: c#, .net, dto

I am a junior developer, just starting out :). I have a project where I have made some Data Transfer Objects (DTO) for an API I have created. I am writting some Unit Tests and wanted the unit and integration tests to use these to pass data and verify responses.

The issue I have is i feel the way i am using them is NOT Best practice and I am repeating myself (DRY).  Could i get some guidance on the matter please?

DTO

```
public class myDTO
{
    public class Request
    {
        public bool enabled{ get; set; }
        public int? age{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then i have a class that uses this in a unit test:

```
public async Task somethingTest()
{

    var request = new myDTO.Request
    {
        enabled= true,
        age     = 21,
        name    = "bob"
    };

    var returnedResponse = await new client().updatePerson(
            string.Format(PersonUri, users, userId),
            request);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, returnedResponse.StatusCode);
}

public async Task somethingTest2()
{

    var request = new myDTO.Request
    {
        enabled= true,
        age     = 28,
        name    = "Gill"
    };

    var returnedResponse = await new client().updatePerson(
            string.Format(PersonUri, users, userId),
            request);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, returnedResponse.StatusCode);
}

public async Task somethingTest3()
{

    var request = new myDTO.Request
    {
        enabled= true,
        age     = 45,
        name    = "tim"
    };

    var returnedResponse = await new client().updatePerson(
            string.Format(PersonUri, users, userId),
            request);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, returnedResponse.StatusCode);
}
```

I cannot help but feel there is a better way to be building the DTO than having it over and over.

Any guidance / help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It would be better to ask this question on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Comment: Thanks Salah, wasn't aware of this site. Will use it from now on!

Answer (score 0):

Since your Assertions are identical in all three tests, these tests are validating very similar scenarii.

Here are some possible changes you could make on these tests to avoid repetition and maybe expand the validations these tests are performing:

- use the [xunit Theory and InlineData/MemberData attributes](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/#using-the-theory-attribute-to-create-parameterised-tests-with-inlinedata-). This way, you only need to write your unit test once and can pass your test scenarii (data) as parameters.
- try to be more precise with your Assertions. I.e., also Assert that your *client* invoked your Repository/DAL's *update* method with the data from the given Request.
- Finally, if you are worried about the coherence of your DTOs over time, for instance if you know that you'll add new properties to the DTO over time, you could consider making the properties of the DTO get-only and initializing them through the constructor.

Comment: Thanks GMIS! The assertions are the same as this is just an example. In the other cases, i would be checking for different status codes.

Comment: How would the code be structured in a Constructor, wouldn't they need to be SET not Get

Comment: public class Request
    {
        public bool Enabled { get; }
        public int Age { get; }
        public string Name { get; }

        public Request(bool enabled, int age, string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(name));
            }

            Enabled = enabled;
            Age = age;
            Name = name;
        }
    }